# Concise flexible struct definition

Tags: python

I need to define a bunch of flexible structs (objects with a simple collection of named fields, where you can add new fields later, but I don't need methods or inheritance or anything like that) in Python 2.7. (The context is that I'm reading stuff from binary files with struct.unpack_from, then adding further data to the results.)

A class meets the requirements, e.g.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

The only downside being that each field name must be written out three times. collections.namedtuple gives a more precise definition syntax but you can't add fields to the resulting objects.

Is there a way to get flexibility of a class with at least some of the brevity of collections.namedtuple?

Comment: Have you considered using dicts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden away in the `argparse` module is `Namespace`:

```
from argparse import Namespace

n = Namespace(foo='Foo', bar='Bar')

n
Out[3]: Namespace(bar='Bar', foo='Foo')

n.bar
Out[4]: 'Bar'

n.hey = 'Hey'

n
Out[6]: Namespace(bar='Bar', foo='Foo', hey='Hey')
```

Comment: Note that in python3.3+ there is a `types.SimpleNamespace`. It's more intuitive to use that because you don't expect to need `argparse` if you are not parsing command lines.

Answer (score 7):

A pattern that I found sometimes useful is

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

and you can use it like

```
p = Obj(x=10, y=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote for this purpose:

```
def initialize(instance, args):
    """
    In __init__, call initialize(self, locals()) to load all passed
    arguments.
    """
    if 'self' in args:
        del args['self']
    for k, v in args.items():
        setattr(instance, k, v)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        initialize(self, locals())

a = MyClass(1, 2, 3)
```

However, in the end I decided that the lack of readability caused by this wasn't worth the keystrokes saved, it wasn't an especially big problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get flexibility of a class with at least some of the
>   brevity of collections.namedtuple?

Just instantiate your class and give it class attributes :

```
class Namespace(object):
    foo = 'bar'
```

and now, `Namespace.foo` returns `'bar'`

Bad style in a script, but in a shell, you can set multiple attributes separated by semicolons:

```
>>> class NameSpace(object): foo = 'bar'; baz = {}
>>> NameSpace.baz['quux'] = 'ni'
>>> NameSpace.foo
'bar'
>>> NameSpace.something = 'completely different'
```

> ... collections.namedtuple?

Well, the above is even more brief, but the below is a bit more similar to `collections.namedtuple`, (makes you wonder where they got the idea, doesn't it?):

```
>>> NameSpace = type('NameSpace', (object,), {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': {}})
>>> NameSpace.baz['quux'] = 'ni'
>>> NameSpace.foo
'bar'
```